# Can i use System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache in cloud web role project?

Tags: wcf, azure, caching, memorycache

I would like to use `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` in Web role project which contains `WCF Service`.

Can anybody please let me know that whether we can use `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` in `Cloud web` role project?

If yes please let me know Memory and other constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

You should add the reference to System.Runtime.Caching to the Web Role project, then use something like the code below (it is doing almost nothing and is not a best practice, for sure).

Just tried it with ASP.NET MVC in the Cloud Web Role with the Azure Emulator and it works.

Regarding limits - there are two CacheMemoryLimit and PhysicalMemoryLimit properties you can use for retrieve the needed values. It shows the limit in bytes. I do not know if there are any limits beyond these in terms of in-memory cache in Azure Cloud Services.

```
private static object _lock = new Object();
    private static MemoryCache _cache = new MemoryCache("ThisIsMyCache");

    public static object GetItem(string key)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            var item = _cache.Get(key);
            if (item == null)
            {
                item = InitiaizeItem(key);
                _cache.Set(key, item, new CacheItemPolicy());
            }
            return item;
        }
    }

    private static object InitiaizeItem(string key)
    {            
        return new { Value = key };
    }
```